# What is the difference between android:contentDescription="@null" and tools:ignore="ContentDescription"? Use android:importantForAccessibility="no"?

Tags: android, android-layout, attributes, imageview, lint

Take this android layout XML snippet for example:

```html
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/bitcoin"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:importantForAccessibility="no"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```

What is the difference between `android:contentDescription="@null"` and `tools:ignore="ContentDescription"?`

I know both of them are used to indicate that a certain non-textual element carries no meaning and is only meant for decoration. Is there an advantage of using one over the other, should I use both, is it preference, or is one considered better and newer than the other?

Also, should I use `android:importantForAccessibility="no"` or is using all three attributes/properties simply overkill?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What is the difference between `android:contentDescription="@null"`
>   and `tools:ignore="ContentDescription"`?

#### android:contentDescription="@null"

- Used to indicate that a certain non-textual element carries no meaning and is only meant for decoration.

#### tools:ignore="ContentDescription"

- For graphical elements, such as `ImageView` and `ImageButton`. If you do not set their respective `android:contentDescription` XML attributes, a lint warning message will be displayed.

  `"Missing contentDescription attribute on image"`
- To suppress this lint warning message then you must use `tools:ignore="ContentDescription"` in XML.

> I know both of them are used to indicate that a certain non-textual
>   element carries no meaning and is only meant for decoration. Is there an advantage of using one over the other, should I use both, is it preference, or is one considered better and newer than the other?

No, they are different from each other in term of usage, for example

```
<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:id="@+id/image_user_avatar"
    android:contentDescription="User avatar"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```

When running the app with TalkBack, it will speak "User avatar".

> Should I use `android:importantForAccessibility="no"`?

If your app only supports devices running Android 4.1 (API level 16) or higher, you can set these elements' `android:importantForAccessibility` XML attributes to `"no"` instead of `android:contentDescription="@null`.

**Update**

> So basically tools:ignore="ContentDescription" is only for the
>   compiler and android:contentDescription="@null" is for user user?

Yes, it is.

> Also, my 'minSdk' is 14 and my 'targetSdk' is 28. Can I still set both
>   android:importantForAccessibility="no" and
>   android:contentDescription="@null"?

Yes, you can set both of them but if you run the app on device whose SDK below 16, `android:importantForAccessibility="no"` will be ignored.

> Will android:contentDescription="@null" have the same effect as
>   android:importantForAccessibility="no" for devices running Android 4.1
>   or higher?

They have slightly difference.

`android:contentDescription="@null"`: The view with this attribute still highlighted when users move finger on it and Accessibility Services will speak out loud dummy text such as "Button", etc.

`android:importantForAccessibility="no"`: The view with this attribute is disabled by the app so it will not highlighted when users move finger on and ignored by Accessibility Services as well.

Comment: So basically tools:ignore="ContentDescription" is only for the compiler and android:contentDescription="@null" is for user user? Also, my 'minSdk' is 14 and my 'targetSdk' is 28. Can I still set both android:importantForAccessibility="no" and android:contentDescription="@null"? Will android:contentDescription="@null" have the same effect as android:importantForAccessibility="no" for devices running Android 4.1 or higher?

Comment: I have an `ImageView` and `android:contentDescription="@null"` but, it still says: `unlabelled`! I tried `android:contentDescription="@string/nothing"` where `<string name="nothing" translatable="false" />` but, it didn't help and TalkBack still says `unlabelled`